# HttpClient and MultipartFormDataContent = upload File an Strings

Tags: c#, httpclient

At first a big sorry for my really bad English :-)

I have a problem since two days. I will upload a file to the https://www.share-online.biz/uploadapi api. But it doesn't work. I wrote this code in C#:

```
FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(DateiPfad);

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

byte[] file = FileToArray(DateiPfad);

form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(file, 0, file.Length), "fn", "test2.rar");
form.Add(new StringContent(Benutzer), "username");
form.Add(new StringContent(Passwort), "password");
form.Add(new StringContent(sessionname), "upload_session");
form.Add(new StringContent("1"), "chunk_no");
form.Add(new StringContent("1"), "chunk_number");
form.Add(new StringContent(Convert.ToString(file.Length)), "filesize");

form.Add(new StringContent("1"), "finalize");

var response = httpClient.PostAsync(server, form).Result;

httpClient.Dispose();
string sd = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

File.WriteAllText("out.txt", sd);
MessageBox.Show("Server: " + sd);
```

and I get this request:

```
*** EXCEPTION session creation/reuse failed - 09-30-2018, 1:09 pm ***
```

The Server, session, password and the username came from another function and working fine.

Can anybody help me pls?

Comment: please don't use `.Result` it will block the thread. Use `async` `await` instead. It is very bad practice. Also if you are getting this error from third-party APIs, try to read about what does that mean from their documentation

Answer (score 0):

For this type of work i use Tiny.RestClient.
https://github.com/jgiacomini/Tiny.RestClient

It's make easier to build mutlipart content.

Another question : are you sure you have to send the username and password as content?